# Pandas Pivot Table alphabetically sorts categorical data (incorrectly) when adding columns parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I ran into trouble with the Pandas pivot function. I am trying to pivot sales data by month and year. The dataset is as follows:

```
Customer - Sales - Month Name   - Year
a        - 100   - january      - 2013
a        - 120   - january      - 2014
b        - 220   - january      - 2013
```

In order to sort the month names correctly I have added a column with the month names as categorical data.

```
dataset['Month'] = dataset['Month Name'].astype('category')
dataset['Month'].cat.set_categories(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],inplace=True)
dataset.pop('Month Name')
```

when I use the function:

```
pt = dataset.pivot_table(values="Sales", index="Month")
```

I get the expected result

```
Month
January      3620302.79
February     3775507.25
March        4543839.69
```

However when I pivot across years and months the months are sorted alphabetically.

```
print dataset.pivot_table(values='Sales', index="Month", columns="Year", aggfunc="sum")
Year            2011        2012        2013        2014
Month                                                   
April      833692.19   954483.28  1210847.85  1210926.61
August     722604.75   735078.52   879905.23  1207211.00
December   779873.51  1053441.71  1243745.73         NaN
```

I would appreciate any help to properly sort the month names in the last code sample.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: So, the result index is ``object`` dtype, as its converted automatically by the pivot, and it is not reordered according to the category. So that's a bug; pandas doesn't support a CategoricalIndex yet, as that would be ideal result. here is the bug report: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8731

Comment: @Frank, I've provided an answer, have you reviewed yet?

Comment: I got a similar problem when I use pivot_table with categorical column and the category has no values in DataFrame pandas sais Cannot convert NA to integer

Answer (score 0):

You're right after `pivot_table` it will reindex the 'Month' and thus sort alphabetically. Luckily you can always convert your `dataset['Month']` to `pandas.datetime` and convert it back to string after `pivot_table`'s reindex.

Not the best solution, but this should do the trick (I use some random dummies):

```
import pandas as pd
...
# convert dataset['Month'] to pandas.datetime by the time of pivot
# it will reindex by datetime hence the sort order is kept
pivoted = dataset.pivot_table(index=pd.to_datetime(dataset['Month']), columns='Year', \
                              values='Sales', aggfunc='sum')
pivoted
Year        2012  2013  2014
Month                       
2014-01-04   151   295   NaN
2014-02-04   279   128   NaN
2014-03-04   218   244   NaN
2014-04-04   274   152   NaN
2014-05-04   276   NaN   138
2014-06-04   223   NaN   209
...

# then re-set the index back to Month string, "%B" means month string "January" etc.
pivoted.index = [pd.datetime.strftime(m, format='%B') for m in pivoted.index]

pivoted
Year       2012  2013  2014
January     151   295   NaN
February    279   128   NaN
March       218   244   NaN
April       274   152   NaN
May         276   NaN   138
June        223   NaN   209
...
```

However you will miss the 'Month' index label, if you need that, you can copy dataset['Month'] to another column (called it `M`) and convert to `datetime`, then set multiple indexes on `pivot_table` like:

```
dataset.pivot_table(index=['M', 'Month'], ...)
```

Comment: What if it's not a date? How do you keep the original order of your index after pivot_table?

Comment: @Cesar, if it's not a date, you can have a custom dictionary mapping the orderings like `{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, ...}`, then it's only a matter of mapping the indexes to its values for *sorting*, then remap them back to meaningful keys. As it stands, there are certainly better solutions but it fits what OP asked for.

Comment: @Anzel For categorical data, pivot orders from A-Z. It caused me problem while ploting a lineplot with NaN value at A. The simple solution is: pivoted.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)

Comment: @MarjanRadfar if you have sorted dataset I guess that will work out for you. For OP this particular answer is intended for sorting indexes based on datetime type/label.